# python, rank a list of number/string (convert list elements to ordinal value)

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Say I have a list (or numpy array or pandas series) as below

```
l = [1,2,6,6,4,2,4]
```

I want to return a list of each value's ordinal, 1-->1(smallest), 2-->2, 4-->3, 6-->4 and

```
to_ordinal(l) == [1,2,4,4,3,2,4]
```

and I want it to also work for list of strings input.

I can try

```
s = numpy.unique(l)
```

then loop over each element in l and find its index in s. Just wonder if there is a direct method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In pandas you can call [`rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rank.html#pandas.Series.rank) and pass `method='dense'`:

```
In [18]:
l = [1,2,6,6,4,2,4]
s = pd.Series(l)
s.rank(method='dense')
Out[18]:
0    1
1    2
2    4
3    4
4    3
5    2
6    3
dtype: float64
```

This also works for strings:

```
In [19]:
l = ['aaa','abc','aab','aba']
s = pd.Series(l)

Out[19]:
0    aaa
1    abc
2    aab
3    aba
dtype: object

In [20]:
s.rank(method='dense')

Out[20]:
0    1
1    4
2    2
3    3
dtype: float64
```

Comment: FYI: You can also use `scipy.stats.rankdata` (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rankdata.html).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is a "direct method" for this<sup>1</sup>.  The most straight forward way that I can think to do it is to sort a set of the elements:

```
sorted_unique = sorted(set(l))
```

Then make a dictionary mapping the value to it's ordinal:

```
ordinal_map = {val: i for i, val in enumerate(sorted_unique, 1)}
```

Now one more pass over the data and we can get your list:

```
ordinals = [ordinal_map[val] for val in l]
```

Note that this is a roughly `O(NlogN)` algorithm (due to the sort) -- And the more non-unique elements you have, the closer it becomes to `O(N)`.

<sup><sup>1</sup>Certainly not in vanilla python and I don't know of anything in `numpy`.  I'm less familiar with `pandas` so I can't speak to that.</sup>